# generic has circular-dependency error because of InstanceType

Tags: typescript-generics

I spend already some hours for investigate issue, and already found one solution which will be used for Ok2 in next example. But I will grateful if somebody can explain me why issue appear with InstanceType, but not in another cases.

```js
export class A {
  constructor(
    // TS2502: "err" is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
    private readonly err: Err,
    private readonly ok1: Ok1,
    private readonly ok2: Ok2,
  ) {}

  fn() {}
}

// TS2456: Type alias "Err" circularly references itself.
export type Err = InstanceType<typeof A>['fn'];

export type Ok1 = A['fn'];

export type Ok2 = (typeof A)['prototype']['fn'];
```

typescript 4.9.4

**Probably explanation**

Because of difference between how is resolved access of property and call of another generic, maybe property access is more smart and doesn't require to full resolve entire base type when is used simple type (like current class), but in case of Err - ['fn'] can't be optimised because is called from another generic, and therefore need for first to execute this generic, but it can't happens because to InstanceType is passed entire type of class A which uses Err which we now try to resolve